# ConnectionRefusedError when trying to connect to different machine, but not the own machine

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, client-server

I've been making a reverse shell application and since now only tried it on the same machine instead of a different one. Everything works fine as expected when using the same machine but when I try two different machines, the machine on which `client.py` runs gives me a `ConnectionsRefusedError`.

The `client.py` code

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def send(s: socket.socket, obj):
    s.send(dumps(obj))


def recv(s: socket.socket):
    return loads(s.recv(1024 * 1000))


while True:
    try:
        server.connect(("server ip", 6969))
        connected = True
    except:
        connected = False
    try:
        key = recv(server)
        if key:
            send(server, None)
        else:
            connected = False
    except:
        connected = False
    loc = my_loc
    while connected:
         # reverse shell script
```

Here is the `server.py` code

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("0.0.0.0", 6969))
server.listen()

def listen():
        global server
        while True:
            conn, addr = server.accept()
            clients[addr[0]] = {"conn": conn, "cmd": {"head": None}, "info": {}, "ping": 0, "allowed": True}
            logs[addr[0]] = []
            shells[addr[0]] = []
            client_threads[addr[0]] = Thread(target=_client, args=(addr[0],))
            client_threads[addr[0]].start()

listener = Thread(target=listen, name="Listener")
listener.start()
```

Thats not the whole code, but the part where I get the errors from.
I had this problem multiple times but always somehow fixed it by moving the `server = socket.socket()` part in `server.py` around.

Is there anything I'm not seeing here?

Comment: `server.connect(("server ip", 6969))` why are you passing a string to `connect`?

Comment: @kiner_shah I didn't put in the real IP for obvious reasons. Thats just a place holder for this post...

Comment: could anyone solve it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Ip for different computers are different.
you will have to check the Ip of the new computer.

I had the same problem:-

1. If you are connected via the same router the Ip will look like 192.168.**.*
   you need this code to get the router IP

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()

ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

print(f"Hostname: {hostname}")
print(f"IP Address: {ip_address}")
```

2. If you are doing socket on a different network then you need to change the router settings to do port forwarding.
   it is different for different routers so look it up.
   Then find your public Ip and change your Ip in the client script.(Do not change IP on server script)